# ElasticSearch field boost

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have the following [ElasticSearch DSL](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/) query

```
query = Q("bool", should=[
    Q("match_phrase", title=term),
    Q("match_phrase", description=term),
    Q("match_phrase", name=term),
    Q("match_phrase", some_other_field=term),
])
```

I would like to boost the score when `term` is matching `name` field and also would like to lower the score when the match is on the `description` field.

I've tried many things, like:

```
Q("match_phrase", description={'query': term, boost: '0.1'}),
```

or

```
Q("match_phrase", name={'query': term, boost: 10}),
```

But couldn't make it work.
I also tried combining should with must, etc, but didn't get too far - not even worth sharing.
Is there a simple way to do it without reindexing/re-scoring all my documents? An answer with a ES query (rather than ES-DSL) would be helpful as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this using [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query and setting the type as `most_fields`. By default multi_match query uses `best_fields` type which

> Finds documents which match any field, but uses the _score from the
>   best field.

Since you want to manipulate score by more than one matching field you have to set type as `most_fields` which

> Finds documents which match any field and combines the _score from
>   each field.

Therefore the query will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "match",
      "type": "most_fields",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "description^-1",
        "name^5",
        "some_other_field"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You might have notice in above query that I have given name a boost of 5 to score higher if match is in `name` and -1 (-ve) boost to reduce the score of match is in `description` field.

This way you can play around with boost values to get the desired score.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This seems to be on the right direction, however, I seemed to have lost highlights (forgot to mention I was using that feature on the question)

Comment: In the end, i think my problem was sorting after trying to boost some fields, the sorting would always mess up with results.. I'm gonna accept your answer  even though it's exactly what did it for me. Ty

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for boosting with `match`. thankfully I found this example.

**Use this**

```
{
    "match": {
        "title": {
            "query": "python",
            "boost": 2
        }
    }
}
```

**instead of**

```
{
    "match": {
        "title": "python"
    }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/blog/how-to-improve-elasticsearch-search-relevance-with-boolean-queries